# vbulletin forum within SilverStripe Root - url misdirection

Tags: .htaccess, silverstripe

We have a vBulletin 5 installation within a SilverStripe root, loaded into a folder named *community*. The url to the community index file should therefore be: `www.e-lumini.com/community`.

However, the url is automatically appended with `./?url=/community` (appearing fully as `http://e-lumini.com/community/?`) and, of course, redirects to a 404 page.

Presumably, this is a `.htaccess` content issue.

Here is our current SilverStripe .htaccess file

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
# Deny access to templates (but allow from localhost)
<Files *.ss>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

# Deny access to IIS configuration
<Files web.config>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny access to YAML configuration files which might include sensitive    
information
<Files *.yml>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Route errors to static pages automatically generated by SilverStripe
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn off index.php handling requests to the homepage fixes issue in apache =2.4
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex disabled
</IfModule>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase '/'

# Deny access to potentially sensitive files and folders
RewriteRule ^community - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]

# Process through SilverStripe if no file with the requested name exists.
# Pass through the original path as a query parameter, and retain the existing parameters.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Note the inclusion of the community rewrite rule just above, which now results in a 403 error.

How do we fix this incorrect url redirect issue?

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the `main.php` `RewriteRule` to check that the URL does not begin with `/community` before redirecting the request to SilverStripe's framework `main.php` file.

To check this we add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/community` to our `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/community 
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]
```

This will stop SilverStripe redirecting access to the `community` URL and any sub URLs. This allows us to put any other application or code into this directory.

We also need to remove the following rule as this blocks all access to the community URL:

```
RewriteRule ^community - [L,NC]
```